# get JSON responses for every dynamically added index DOM elements with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to get json response from api, and consequently do events in JQuery for dynamically added DOM elements in HTML.

I can show json messages for every index elements.

```
        function checkIdnAvailability() {
            var jsonRsp = [];
            $('.iin').each(function (index) {
                    var tb0001_idn_val = $('#iin'+index).val();
                    $.post("<?php echo site_url()?>college/idnCheck", {
                        tb0001_idn: tb0001_idn_val
                    }, function(response){
                        $('#loading').hide();
                        $('#message'+index).html('').html(response.message).show();
                        jsonRsp.push(response.message);
                        if($.inArray("data exists", jsonRsp)) {
                            $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
                        }else {
                            $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
                        }
                    });

                }
            )
        }
```

Here i want to say that if i get "data exists" json response i want to disable submit button.

Comment: And the problem is...?

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález the code does not work!

Comment: There's no need to call `.html('')` before `.html(response.message)`, since `.html()` will completely replace whatever is there.

Comment: Have to provide more information.  What error are you getting? what does the response look like?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've pushed "data exists" into the array, it will still exist after all future AJAX responses are received. So you only need to disable the submit button when you receive one of these responses, then it can stay disabled.

```
function checkIdnAvailability() {
  $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
  $('.iin').each(function(index) {
    var tb0001_idn_val = $('#iin' + index).val();
    $.post("<?php echo site_url()?>college/idnCheck", {
      tb0001_idn: tb0001_idn_val
    }, function(response) {
      $('#loading').hide();
      $('#message' + index).html(response.message).show();
      if (response.message == "data exists") {
        $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for reply. I tried your code, but the submit button stays disabled even data does not exist

Comment: I don't see how that can be. Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the `.prop('disabled', true)` line to see how you're getting there?